# printing out returned value from method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I need to know how to print out the return value from the method

```
public double ConvertToFar(double a)
{
    double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);
    double b=9.0;
    double c=5.0;
    double d=32.0;
    double f = a * (b / c) + d;

    return f;
}

public double ConvertToCel(double a,double b,double c,double d,double e)
{
    double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);
    b=32.0;
    c=5.0;
    d=9.0;
    e = (a - b) * (c / d);

    return e;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        label3.Text = ConvertToFar(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a)).ToString();
    }
}
```

the error says "The best overloaded method match for 'Temperature1.Form1.ConvertToFar(double)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Why do you pass parameter `a` when you aren't using it as input, but instead working off of the `textBox1.Text` value. You should probably parse `a` *first*, then pass `a` to your functions and *not* refer to the text box there.

Comment: This is pretty much the same question you posted yesterday I think.(though slightly improved.) I still say you need to learn a little more about C# by doing some tutorials or reading a book.

Comment: For reference, this was what you asked yesterday (using a different account) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164145/how-to-return-values-from-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your code to the following one:

```
double a;

if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a))
   label3.Text = ConvertToFar(a).ToString();
```

The `TryParse` method returns a `bool` not a `double`. Specifically, it returns `true`, if the parse succeeds. Otherwise returns `false`.

The reason why you were getting this error is the fact that `ConvertToFar` method takes as a parameter a `double` and not a `bool`.

**Update**

One side note is that I don't think you need this `double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);` in both your methods. You already pass a double to your methods, which is associated with the text inserted in textbox with id `textBox1`.

Furthermore, there is no need pass any further parameter to `ConvertToCel` except from the temperature in Fahrenheit. The other values you need to do the calculation should be local variables as below. You don't have to alter their values. This is a good catch made by [juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr). Please see below in comments.

I mean that your methods should change as below:

```
public double ConvertToFar(double a)
{
    double b=9.0;
    double c=5.0;
    double d=32.0;
    double f = a * (b / c) + d;

    return f;
}

public double ConvertToCel(double a)
{
    b=32.0;
    c=5.0;
    d=9.0;
    e = (a - b) * (c / d);

    return e;
}
```

Comment: I understand changing the code but, are you saying the fi statemtn you wrote above should still go into the converttofar method or I should put it outside the method @Christos

Comment: You should put it inside the if statement of your button's click handler,  `if (radioButton1.Checked == true){ \\here }`. Is that clear?

Comment: Also there's no reason to have b, c, d, or e as method parameters for `ConvertToCel`, they should just be local variables.

Comment: @juharr sure thing. You are pretty correct dude. Shame on me...I didn't notice this.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
             {
                 bool success = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);

                 if (success) // check if it was parsed successful
                 {
                     label3.Text = ConvertToFar(a).ToString(); // now set it in label
                 }
             }
         }

Comment: This is also correct. Now you have that you want :) .

Comment: @Christos I am still getting the error "Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'double.TryParse(string, out double)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @yemioladejo one question have you declared the variable `a`. I mean have you done this `double a`, before you pass it in the `double.TryParse` method ?

Comment: no i hadn't, i have just corrected it and it now works, thanks for your help, do you know where i can learn a lot more about the use of local variables

Comment: I am glad that I helped :). I don't think that you need a resource for local variables as you need a resource for learning C#. I would suggest you buy two books that are awesome and they will help as you can't imagine in your C# learning journey.

Comment: The one is this http://www.amazon.com/Pro-NET-Framework-Experts-Voice/dp/1430242337/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1412341666&sr=8-9&keywords=learning+c%23 and the second one is this http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Object-Oriented-Programming-Experts-Voice/dp/1430249358/ref=sr_1_17?ie=UTF8&qid=1412341797&sr=8-17&keywords=C%23. Provided that you will invest your time on reading them and trying as many examples that you will find there, you will be at another level very soon.

Comment: Ok then thanks again and one more thing, will the book have any info on debugging, i not sure how to debug with visual studio at all

Comment: You welcome dude. If i remember correct, the first one yes, it has.

Answer (score 4):

`TryParse()` returns `bool` which tells parsing was successful or not:

```
double number;
bool success = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out number); // returns true or false

if(success) // check if it was parsed successful
{
label3.Text = ConvertToFar(number).ToString(); // now set it in label
}
```

Comment: when I set it in the label it says that the name 'a' does not exist in the current context

Comment: make it global in class

Answer (score 2):

`double.TryParse` returns a bool result that indicates whether parse was successful. You need to pass the `double` value to your method

```
if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a))
   label3.Text = ConvertToFar(a).ToString();
```

Comment: But his `ConvertToFar` also needs to change to *not* `TryParse` again.